# How to use ffmpeg to programatically remove video streams?

Tags: ffmpeg, batch, cmd.exe, mp4box

So, I'm trying to refactor some old code that should remove video streams, compress the audio stream and repack the mp4, which should be a video file with only an audio stream. I later intend to replicate it to work with .wmv.

According to the author, it works like this:

1. Use mediainfo.exe to get AudioStreamID (1 or 2)

   ```
   mediaindo --inform=Audio;%ID% "filename.mp4"
   ```
2. Use mp4box.exe and ID from above to extract audio track. Eg. with ID=1:

   ```
   mp4box -raw 1 "filename.mp4" -out "filename.aac"
   ```
3. Compress audio track with ffmpeg.exe and fdkaac.exe

   ```
   ffmpeg -i "filename.aac" -f caf - | fdkaac -b16 -I -p29 - -o "filename.m4a"
   ```
4. Remove old audio and video tracks and add a new compressed audio track

   ```
   mp4box -rem 1 -rem 2 -add "filename.m4a" "filename.mp4"
   ```

Then someone else put it into batch:

```
@echo off
echo CBFT MP4 to SDVL converter
chcp 65001>nul
echo %~n1
setlocal
set mp4box=P:\progz\multimedia\gpac\mp4box.e xe -quiet
set ffmpeg=P:\progz\multimedia\ffmpeg\bin\ff mpeg.exe -hide_banner -v 0
set fdkaac=P:\progz\multimedia\fdkaac\fdkaac .exe
set mediainfo=P:\progz\multimedia\MediaInfo\ MediaInfo.exe
for /R %1 %%f in (*.mp4) do (
echo.
echo %%~nxf
if exist "%%~dpnf.aac" del "%%~dpnf.aac">nul
if exist "%%~dpnf.m4a" del "%%~dpnf.m4a">nul
for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=:" %%a in (
'%mediainfo% --inform^=Audio^;%%ID%%:%%Duration/String3%% "%%f"') do (
echo %%c
%mp4box% -raw %%a "%%f" -out "%%~dpnf.aac" )
%ffmpeg% -i "%%~dpnf.aac" -f caf - | %fdkaac% -b16 -I -p29 - -o "%%~dpnf.m4a"
%mp4box% -flat -rem 1 -rem 2 -add "%%~dpnf.m4a":name= "%%f"
if exist "%%~dpnf.aac" del "%%~dpnf.aac">nul
if exist "%%~dpnf.m4a" del "%%~dpnf.m4a">nul
)
endlocal
```

And it seemed to work by then, with mp4. Now it breaks in the ffmpeg part, here is my attempt to rebuild it until now:

```
echo CBFT MP4 to SDVL converter
chcp 65001>nul
echo %~n1
for /R %1 %%f in (*.mp4) do (

echo STARTING
echo %%~nxf
if exist "%%~dpnf.aac" del "%%~dpnf.aac"
if exist "%%~dpnf.m4a" del "%%~dpnf.m4a"

echo start ABOVE
echo mediainfo BELOW
pause

for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=:" %%a in (
'mediainfo --inform^=Audio^;%%ID%%:%%Duration/String3%% "%%f"') do (
echo %%c
mp4box -raw %%a "%%f" -out "%%~dpnf.aac" )

echo mp4box ABOVE
echo ffmpeg BELOW
pause

## This line should compress the audio stream ##

echo ffmpeg ABOVE
echo mp4box BELOW
pause

mp4box -flat -rem 1 -rem 2 -add "%%~dpnf.m4a":name= "%%f"
if exist "%%~dpnf.aac" del "%%~dpnf.aac"
if exist "%%~dpnf.m4a" del "%%~dpnf.m4a"
)
endlocal
```

Note that it's missing the stream compression section and that I removed fdkaac completely. I'm also guessing that the whole process could be done by a single ffmpeg command (plus the looping part), which would be specially useful when I try to get it to work with the .wmv files.

Could you give some directions on what I should do? That single ffmpeg command, if it is possible, or help me with multiple of them so I make them all work together?

To clarify: my goal is to reproduce steps 1 through 4 with ffmpeg. I believe there *are* capabilities to filter out streams and probably they're way more economic than this old code. How should I use ffmpeg for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know have a final, working version, even though it could use some improvement on the `-f` section:

## The whole thing (after checking that ffmpeg is available)

```dos
:: Actual converting ::

for /r "%~1" %%V in (*.mp4, *.wmv, *.mkv, *.avi, *.webm, *.mov, *.m4v) do (
    for /f "tokens=* delims=." %%A in ("%%~xV") do set ext=%%A
    if !ext!==mkv set ext=matroska
    if !ext!==webm set ext=matroska
    if !ext!==wmv set ext=asf
    ffmpeg -err_detect ignore_err -fflags +igndts -i "%%~fV" -f !ext! -codec:a copy -map 0 -map -0:v -map -0:s -b:a 32k "%%~pnxV.tmpsdvl"
)

:: Moving and Renaming ::

robocopy "%~f1" "SDVL\%~n1" *.tmpsdvl /s /mov
for /r "SDVL\%~n1" %%B in (*.TMPSDVL) do ren %%~fB %%~nB
```

## Breaking it down

### The FFmpeg string

`ffmpeg -err_detect ignore_err -fflags +igndts -i "%%~fV" -f !ext! -codec:a copy -map 0 -map -0:v -map -0:s -b:a 32k "%%~pnxV.tmpsdvl"`

#### What it does

- `-err_detect ignore_err` and `-fflags +igndts` are some measures taken to power through some common errors;
- `-i "%%~fV"` is the full qualified path to my input, since I'm running a `for` loop;
- `-f !ext!` ensures the output uses the format from the previously specified variable. This approach will be clarified below;
- `-codec:a copy` tells fmmpeg to use the same encoder for the audio stream;
- `-map 0` selects all streams from the file;
- `-map -0:v` then deselects all video streams;
- `-map -0:s` deselects every subtitle stream;
- `-b:a 32k` sets the audio quality to 32kbps CBR;
- `"%%~pnxV.tmpsdvl"` generates the output in the same directory as the input, but with the extension `.tmpsdvl` added.

### The loop

```dos
for /r "%~1" %%V in (*.mp4, *.wmv, *.mkv, *.avi, *.webm, *.mov, *.m4v) do (
    for /f "tokens=* delims=." %%A in ("%%~xV") do set ext=%%A
    if !ext!==mkv set ext=matroska
    if !ext!==webm set ext=matroska
    if !ext!==wmv set ext=asf
```

#### What it does

This `for` loop goes through every filetype specified in the parenthesis `()` in the input folder (which is the first passed argument, `"%~1"`) and uses each match as `%%V`. Before actually running `ffmpeg`, we need to define a variable, !ext!, as simply passing an extension to `ffmpeg -f` won't necessarily work. We also need to trim the leading `.` in %%xV. This is the only point I believe needs improvement, as I manually had to e.g. convert `mkv` to `matroska` in this section.

### The moving and renaming

```dos
robocopy "%~f1" "SDVL\%~n1" *.tmpsdvl /s /mov
for /r "SDVL\%~n1" %%B in (*.TMPSDVL) do ren %%~fB %%~nB
```

#### What it does

This is a bit trivial, but for the sake of thoroughness, this scoops every .tmpsdvl file from the folder this command was applied to and moves it to a separate folder, preserving the original structure. It then ingenuously renames every file to a version without an extension, and since we had `file.ext.tmpsdvl`, we easily get `file.ext`

## Notes

- The chosen quality was 32kbps because .wmv files will need at least a 24kbps audio stream;
- There's still room for improvement in the section where it was necessary to specify `ffmpeg -f`. Perhaps by using `ffprobe`.

## References

- [FFmpeg Encoding and Editing Course](https://slhck.info/ffmpeg-encoding-course), by Werner Robitza;
- [FFmpeg Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/documentation.html);
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38162168/12194725) on negative mapping, by [llogan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1109017/llogan)@StackOverflow.
- Steve Jansen's excellent [batch course](https://steve-jansen.github.io/guides/windows-batch-scripting/index.html);
- The very helpful [section on batch](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchstart.php) on Rob van der Weude's website;
- [Computer Hope](https://www.computerhope.com)'s section on [MS-DOS](https://www.computerhope.com/msdos.htm)
- [DosTips - The DOS Batch Guide](https://dostips.com);
- And a ton of scattered answers on StackExchange!

Answer (score 1):

> ffmpeg  -v error -stats -i input.mp4 -vn -sn -dn -acodec libmp3lame
> -ab 192k -ar 41000 output.mp3

or

> -acodec aac -ab 265k out.m4a

or `-acodec copy`    for no compression

Comment: Ha, I actually found about `-acodec copy` somewhere else and came up with a similar solution :)